# Convert DateTime to US Data format with time

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to output datetime in US format with time. I would like to see the output something like "03/10/2017 18:16:46"

Comment: what language are you using to pull the data from the SQL server database?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/

Comment: We use C# .NET.

Comment: Why aren't you doing date formatting in your C# code?

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of [**`convert()`** styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)+' '+convert(varchar(8),getdate(),114)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CRP29768

returns: `03/10/2017 21:30:24`

---

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
select format(getdate(), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

returns: `03/10/2017 21:30:24`

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: Thought about this solution just want to confirm is there any other better method. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wise to mention the format() performance +1.  Like Soy Sauce, should be used sparingly.